# how do I escape a Bullet character in javascript so tomcat won't die from ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, tomcat, urlencode

I am trying to submit some user types text to the server via ajax. If the user types a bullet character via alt key codes (alt-keypad7) • everything breaks. I am using the javascript "escape()" function on the text and the resulting encoding %u2022 for the character. This gets sent back to tomcat and tomcat dies with the following exception.

Mar 10, 2011 10:11:11 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters processParameters
WARNING: Parameters: Character decoding failed. Parameter skipped.
java.io.CharConversionException: isHexDigit

I'm willing to convert the • to `&#8226;` if needs be, but my attempt to do such doesn't work.

```
value = value.replace("•","& #8226;"); //Replace bullets
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to escape or url encode the characters using javascript so this will work correctly and retain the bullet in the text?

Comment: Why are they typing bullet characters in there?

Comment: I'm building a simplified email template wizard, where a user can modify templates to their linking... So if a user where to copy and past out of word a bullet this is what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
value = escape(value).replace("%u2022","&#8226;");
```

Comment: that was close enough, here was the resulting answer... escape(value).replace(/%u2022/gi,"%26%238226%3B");  Since it was the encoded string I had to escape the &, # and ; in that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `&bull;`

---